# Plotting an displacement/velocity map in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, data-analysis

I have a dataset that is composed of an r-component (from 0 to 2mm, separated into 109 step sizes), a z-component (from 0 to 1mm, separated into 109 step sizes) and a displacement profile calculated at 1000 time points for each corresponding r and z coordinate.

I'd like to make a python plot that is similar to [this displacement map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAnw5.png) where each r-coordinate is mapped to a certain time point and corresponding displacement profile along the r-direction at that time point.

I've been trying to plot this for a while using imshow(), which did not work for me because it only takes a single argument or pcolormesh, which does not work because my time and r-coordinate are different lengths.

I've attempted: 
plt.scatter(r_coord, time, c=velocity[0]) to even see a single time point or
plt.imshow(velocity)

Am I missing something? Does anyone have a solution? I would really appreciate some help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted?  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Added some example code!